# How can I get list of all things supported by thing-at-point?

Tags: symbols, thing-at-point

I want a complete list of *things* that works with `thing-at-point`. The documentation states:

```
Possibilities include `symbol`, `list`, `sexp`, `defun`,
`filename`, `url`, `email`, `word`, `sentence`, `whitespace`,
`line`, and `page`.

See the file `thingatpt.el` for documentation on how to define a
valid THING.
```

Because users can dynamically define new *things*, I'm assuming this list needs to be dynamically computed. Things are defined by adding the appropriate properties to a [symbol](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Plists.html#Symbol-Plists). Is it possible to get a list of all symbols that has a given property?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, sure - use [`mapatoms`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html):

```lisp
(defun find-symbols-having-properties (properties)
  (let (ret)
    (mapatoms (lambda (s)
                (when (cl-loop for prop in properties
                               thereis (get s prop))
                    (push s ret))))
    ret))
```

Now, to get all the "things", we need to do

```
(find-symbols-having-properties
 '(beginning-op end-op bounds-of-thing-at-point thing-at-point forward-op))
==> (email url line git-revision list number buffer defun filename uuid sexp)
```

**PS**. You might not necessarily find *all* defined things, but the code should put you on the right path...

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to test for properties `beginning-op`, `end-op`, `bounds-of-thing-at-point`, and `thing-at-point`. A thing can instead be defined by property **`forward-op`** or by a **`forward-`** *THING* function.  (And some uses of things require the existence of a `forward-op` or a `forward-` *THING* function.)

Library [**`thing-cmds.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointCommands) ([code](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thing-cmds.el)) defines these functions:

- **`thgcmd-defined-thing-p`**: Return non-`nil` if `THING` (type) is defined as a thing-at-point type. `THING` is a symbol.
- **`thgcmd-things-alist`**:

> `thgcmd-things-alist` is a compiled Lisp function in thing-cmds.el.
>
> `(thgcmd-things-alist &optional REQUIRE-FWD-P)`
>
> List of most thing types currently defined.
>
> Each is a string that names a type of text entity for which there is a
>   either a corresponding `forward-` thing operation, or corresponding
>   `beginning-of-` thing and `end-of-` thing operations.  The list
>   includes the names of the symbols that satisfy
>   `thgcmd-defined-thing-p`, but with these excluded: `thing`, `buffer`,
>   `point`.
>
> Non-nil arg `REQUIRE-FWD-P` means exclude `THING`s that do not have an
>   associated `forward-THING` function.

This is the definition of `thgcmd-defined-thing-p`, which sounds like what you're looking for:

```lisp
(defun thgcmd-defined-thing-p (thing)
  "Return non-nil if THING (type) is defined as a thing-at-point type.
THING is a symbol."
  (let ((forward-op    (or (get thing 'forward-op)
                           (intern-soft (format "forward-%s" thing))))
        (beginning-op  (get thing 'beginning-op))
        (end-op        (get thing 'end-op))
        (bounds-fn     (get thing 'bounds-of-thing-at-point))
        (thing-fn      (get thing 'thing-at-point)))
    (or (functionp forward-op)
        (and (functionp beginning-op)  (functionp end-op))
        (functionp bounds-fn)
        (functionp thing-fn))))
```

---

There is also user option **`thing-types`**:

> **`thing-types`** is a variable defined in `thing-cmds.el`.
>
> Its value is
>
> `("sexp" "button" "char" "char-same-line" "color" "comment"
>   "decimal-number" "defun" "email" "filename" "hex-number" "line" "list"
>   "list-contents" "non-nil-symbol-name" "number" "overlay" "page"
>   "paragraph" "region-or-word" "sentence" "string" "string-contents"
>   "symbol" "symbol-name" "unquoted-list" "url" "whitespace"
>   "whitespace-&-newlines" "word")`
>
> Documentation:
>
> List of thing types.
>
> Each is a string that names a type of text entity for which there is a
>   either a corresponding `forward-`thing operation, or corresponding
>   `beginning-of-`thing and `end-of-`thing operations.
>
> The default value includes the names of most symbols that satisfy
>   `thgcmd-defined-thing-p` at the time the `defcustom` is evaluated.
>   These types are excluded: `thing`, `buffer`, `point`.
>
> **`M-@`** cycles through this list, in order.
>
> You can customize this variable.

The actual default value depends on your setup. This is the sexp that is evaluated at `defcustom` time to produce the default value:

```lisp
(let ((types  ()))
  (mapatoms
   (lambda (tt)
     (when (thgcmd-defined-thing-p tt) (push (symbol-name tt) types))))
  (setq types  (sort types #'string-lessp))
  ;; Remove types that do not make sense.
  (dolist (typ  '("sexp" "thing" "buffer" "point"))
    (setq types (delete typ types)))
  (setq types  (cons "sexp" types))) ; Put `sexp' first.
```

The option is used in command `cycle-select-something`, and it could also be useful in other contexts:

> **`cycle-select-something`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `thing-cmds.el`.
>
> It is bound to **`M-@`**.
>
> `(cycle-select-something)`
>
> Select something at or near point.  Successively select different things.
>
> The default thing type is the first element of option **`thing-types`**.
>
> In Transient Mark mode, you can follow this with **`C-M-SPC`** to select
>   successive things of the same type, but to do that you must first use
>   `C-x C-x`: `M-@ C-x C-x C-M-SPC`.
>
> If option **`thgcmd-use-nearest-thing-flag`** and non-`nil` then use a thing
>   that is *near*, not necessarily at, point.